# Implicit conversions and null

Tags: scala, operators, string-concatenation

Following code

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

object myObj {
  implicit def nullToInt(x: Null) = 0

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val x = 1 + null
    val y = 1 + nullToInt(null)

    println(x + " " + y)
  }
}
```

gives below result

```
1null 1
```

I was expecting both vals to be Int and equal to 1.

Apparently first val is String and equals "1null".

`Xprint:typer` shows that source code is translated into

```
package <empty> {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions;
  object myObj extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): myObj.type = {
      myObj.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    implicit def nullToInt(x: Null): Int = 0;
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val x: String = 1.+(null);
      val y: Int = 1.+(myObj.this.nullToInt(null));
      scala.Predef.println(x.+(" ").+(y))
    }
  }
}
```

There are no symbolic methods for int which accept null

```
scala> 10+null
res0: String = 10null

scala> 10*null
<console>:12: error: overloaded method value * with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (Null)
       10*null
         ^

scala> 10-null
<console>:12: error: overloaded method value - with alternatives:
  (x: Double)Double <and>
  (x: Float)Float <and>
  (x: Long)Long <and>
  (x: Int)Int <and>
  (x: Char)Int <and>
  (x: Short)Int <and>
  (x: Byte)Int
 cannot be applied to (Null)
       10-null
         ^
```

I assume both "1" and "null" were converted into String instead of applying implicit nullToInt. Can someone explain **how compiler came up with that? What logic/workflow was used?**

And another question is **whether there is a way to enable implcit nullToInt?**

PS. I'm not talking about best practices here. Feel free to consider a question as a matter of academic interest.

Comment: Not an answer, not a suggestion to improve the question, but just a fun fact to contrast the strange behavior of `+` with any other method (here `+++`): `import language.implicitConversions;
class I { def +++(i: I) = "I +++ I" }; 
class S { def +++(a: Any) = "S +++ Any" }; 
class N;

implicit def n2i(n: N): I = new I;
implicit def i2s(i: I): S = new S;

println((new I) +++ (new N));` This converts `N` to `I` and invokes `+++` of the `I`, not that of the `S`. I'm not sure why it works the other way round with `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to answer my own question.

The subject is a bit misleading and in fact no implicit conversions are applied to the expression for val x at all. `Null` is a subtype of `String` and Int has method `abstract def +(x: String): String` so it can be applied to Null as well.

This is also confirmed by the output of `Xprint:typer` because it's supposed to show all implicit conversions and apparently it does not show anything for expression for x.

And answering questions "whether there is a way to enable implcit nullToInt", the only way to enable it is to specify explicitly in this case, because compiler will not consider using any implicits when code is successfully compiled without them.

Comment: Oh, well... Ok, then it's (almost) obvious. So, the initial assumption of the question *"There are no symbolic methods for int which accept null"* turned out to be not entirely correct. I should have double-checked that before continuing with the search for implicit conversions :]

Comment: Great, thanks to this I changed my answer, it was simpler than I thought now that you mentioned there is no way there could be a conversion.  I did a debug and notice it jumped right into StringBuffer. I decided just to see what `any2addString` did. See the amended answer.

Answer (score 3):

So, what @AndreyTyukin says is right, mechanically I think there is more to it. There are two things that are going on as to why.

1. `Any` is decorated with an `implicit` in the `Predef`, see the following:

   `implicit final class any2stringadd[A] extends AnyVal`

As you can see, `any2stringadd` is what is responsible for the `+` and you can see the signature here:

```
def +(other: String): String
```

*Correction:* There are no `implicit conversions`, it was even simpler than that

2. Looking inside the source code of `Predef` and `any2stringadd` which is indeed at play is the following

`implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
        def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
    }`

`String.valueOf` of `1` will return a `String` of `1`.  In Java (and verify with a jshell), a `String` of `1` added to `null` will become `1null`.

```
jshell> "1" + null
$1 ==> "1null"
```

Comment: The `implicitly[Null => String]` is actually the same object as `implicitly[Null <:< String]`, and this object exists because, as I said, `Null` is subtype of all `AnyRef` types, in particular a subtype of `String`. I'm somewhat surprised that there is `any2stringadd`, I thought it was merely a little documentation glitch, and the method was actually on `Any`, but indeed, there is this conversion.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the last paragraph about `augmentString` etc. - what was it supposed to demonstrate? The expression `new StringOps(null)` crashes with a NullPointerException in the REPL. Even though there is an `any2stringadd`, I still don't understand why it is applied to the integer `1` instead of converting the argument.

Comment: Yes, @AndreyTyukin I forgot to mention that. On a REPL it does fail because I guess it tries to return a String interpretation for every line.  But running in an application or script it does return the `String` of `null`.  `augmentString` is needed to wrap `java.lang.String` with a `StringOps` which probably should've been called `RichString`. So what I think is happening is that `augmentString` is called, and then when it realizes that it needs to immediately `unaugmentString` and just becomes a `String`.  A `null` should never have been augmented.

Comment: Ok, alright: `scala.Predef.unaugmentString(new StringOps(null))` indeed returns String `"null"` in the repl - that's fine. But it still does not explain why `1 + null` does not simply convert `null` to `0` and return `1`. In my comment under the question, the `+++` method does exactly that: it converts the argument of type `N` to `I`, and then invokes `+++` of `I` to produce `I +++ I`. So, the *right* operand is implicitly converted. In the case of `1 + null`, the *left* operand seems to be implicitly converted. Why is that?

Comment: Because the actual call for `1 + "Foo"` is `any2stringadd(1) + "Foo"` and since `null` is a String thanks to `augment`/`unaugment` laundering, it is now a `String` called `"null"`. As per what it should return, I'll disagree, I think `1 + null` should be a compile error like it is in Java, `bad operand types for binary operator '+'`.

Comment: By the way, if anyone uses IntelliJ, do a CMD+SHIFT+A/CTRL+SHIFT+A,  and select "Show implicit hints" and it shows what it is actually calling. At first I didn't believe it, but now I think it does a great job. ;)

Comment: Does intelliJ claim that there is some `augment`/`unaugment` laundering involved? Does the actual compiler think in the same way? After reading the specification more closely, I now believe that the compiler actually should prefer the `any2stringadd` implicit conversion before attempting to convert `null`, so everything fits together. So, I'd expect that it is interpreted as `any2stringadd(1).+(null)`, without any `augment`/`unaugment`.

Comment: I expect that too, `null` should never be going to `augment` and then `unaugment`. Since `augment` and `unaugment` should be reserved for decorating `String`

Comment: Thanks for option "Show implicit hints". It;s available only in 2018.2 and not in 2018.1 so I did not know about it. However when I show hints and make them explicit I'm getting following code for my example:   `implicit def nullToInt(x: Null) = 0; val x = 1 + Predef.Character2char(null); val y = 1 + nullToInt(null); println(Predef.any2stringadd(x) + " " + y);`. Of course it provides not the same result as original code.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I'm not convinced that "scala.Predef.unaugmentString(new StringOps(null))" is happening because 1) StringOps is not visible in my source code 2) Scala does not allow double conversions like implicit1(implicit2(argument))